# Правильное написание местоимения "вы"

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В диалоговых текстах нужно ли писать местоимения "вы", "вам" с прописной буквы?
Например:
- Здравствуйте, Игорь, - поприветствовал его руководитель. – Вы ведь уже закончили обучение? – Игорь кивнул. – Очень хорошо. Жду от Вас успешного прохождения сертификации. У руководства на Вас с коллегами большие виды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С прописной буквы пишутся местоимения *Вы* и *Ваш* для выражения вежливого обращения к одному лицу.

При обращении к нескольким лицам или неопределенному кругу лиц местоимения *вы, ваш* пишутся со строчной буквы